# Recursivly removing unecessary nesting in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, ecmascript-6

Here is sample array of objects:

```
const test = [
  {
    properties: {
      test1: "aa",
      test2: "bb",
      button: [
        {
          properties: {
            btnTest1: "aa",
            btnTest2: "bb"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    properties: {
      test1: "aa",
      test2: "bb",
      button: [
        {
          properties: {
            btnTest1: "aa",
            btnTest2: "bb"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
  }
]
```

Using recursive function i want somehow to be able get rid of `"properties"` key so the result will be:

```
const test = [
  {
    test1: "aa",
    test2: "bb",
    button: [
      {
        btnTest1: "aa",
        btnTest2: "bb"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
     test1: "aa",
     test2: "bb",
     button: [
       {
         btnTest1: "aa",
         btnTest2: "bb"
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

I'm struggling to achive this and i don't really have any code that im working on to share here.
Thanks to anyone who are willing to help.

Comment: What is the expected result if the properties objects aren't identical?

Comment: Your desired output has an object with twice the `test1` property. And your original object has an object with twice the  `properties` property... Seems you want something different...

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad... i corrected my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take various checks and create new objects without unwanted property.

```js
function remove(value) {
    if (!value || typeof value !== 'object') return value;
    if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.map(remove);
    if ('properties' in value) return remove(value.properties);
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(value).map(([k, v]) => [k, remove(v)]));
}

const test = [{ properties: { test1: "aa", test2: "bb", button: [{ properties: { btnTest1: "aa", btnTest2: "bb" } }] }}, { properties: { test1: "aa", test2: "bb", button: [{ properties: { btnTest1: "aa", btnTest2: "bb" } }] } }];

console.log(remove(test));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I ran into a problem that Object.fromEntries is not supported until node version > 12.
My node version is v12.16.3, any cure for that?

Comment: a newer node version? otherwise, you could reduce the array: `return Object.entries(value).reduce((o, [k, v]) => { o[k] = remove(v); return o; }, {});`

Comment: You're the best, works like a charm :)
But i definitely need some more time to understand the whole function.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is somewhat different from the other answers.  First, it makes the property name to alter (here `"properties"`) configurable.  More importantly, this does not assume that `"properties"` (or whatever) is the only property of the object being modified.  So

```js
{
  foo: 42,
  properties: {bar: 'abc'}
}
```

would become

```js
{
  foo: 42,
  bar: 'abc'
}
```

That feature may or may not be important to you, but it's an interesting alternative.

This does allow for some ambiguities.  In this implementation, if a name is defined in the root and inside properties, the latter will overwrite the former.  But that could be easily changed.

```js
const flatProp = (p) => (o) => 
  Array .isArray (o)
    ? o .map (flatProp (p))
  : Object (o) === o
    ? Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .flatMap (
        ([k, v]) =>  k === p 
          ? Object .entries (v) .map (([k, v]) => [k, flatProp(p)(v)]) 
          : [[k, v]]
      ))
  : o


const input = [{properties: {test1: "aa", test2: "bb", button: [{properties: {btnTest1: "aa", btnTest2: "bb"}}]}}, {properties: {test1: "aa", test2: "bb", button: [{properties: {btnTest1: "aa", btnTest2: "bb"}}]}}]

console .log (flatProp ('properties') (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Of course this curried function can be partially applied if you prefer:

```js
const upgradeProperties = flatProp ('properties')

console .log (upgradeProperties (input))
```

If you are stuck in an environment without `Object.fromEntries`, it's quite easy to shim.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method with `for..in` loop to also iterate through object in cases there is no `properties` key. This solution assumes that when there is `properties` key there are no other keys in that object.

```js
const test = [{"properties":{"test1":"aa","test2":"bb","button":[{"properties":{"btnTest1":"aa","btnTest2":"bb"}}]}},{"properties":{"test1":"aa","test2":"bb","button":[{"properties":{"btnTest1":"aa","btnTest2":"bb"}}]}}]

function f(data) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (e.properties) {
      r.push(...f([e.properties]))
    } else {
      const o = {}

      for (let p in e) {
        if (Array.isArray(e[p])) {
          o[p] = f(e[p])
        } else {
          o[p] = e[p]
        }
      }

      r.push(o)
    }

    return r
  }, [])
}

console.log(f(test))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would say that's more complicated than i thought....